# Android and orfox/orbot setup

Tags: support, startup

I have tried setting this up and cannot get orfox to load any pages. It is definitely some sort of failure to connect, but orbot says it's 100% bootstrapped. I tried following set up instructions, but I don't show some of the options that it lists. This is on an Android phone, I have nordvpn, orbot, orfox. I know this is vague, but I need to walk through this with some feedback. Where do I start?

Answer (score 0):

Sometime i even get into this problem when i change network i.e. from WIFI to Mobile data and vice versa.
Try resetting the orbot and orfox app in android. (without uninstalling the app)
(Warning : may lose your bookmarks and data/password)
Settings-->App Management-->Clear data and clear cache.